# How to limit access in Cloud Foundry

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloud Foundry.
Is there any way that only specific users  can view and update an app deployed in Cloud Foundry?

1.I deployed an app in Cloud Foundry using “cf push”command.
2.After entering “cf push “command  I’ve got an message below.

```
    Using manifest file /home/stevemar/node-hello-world/manifest.yml
    enter Creating app node-hello-world-example...

name:              node-hello-world-example
requested state:   started
routes:            {route-information}
last uploaded:     Mon 14 Sep 13:46:54 UTC 2020
stack:             cflinuxfs3
buildpacks:        sdk-for-nodejs
type:            web
instances:       1/1
memory usage:    256M
```

3.Using the {route-information} above,I can see the app deployed via browser entering below URL.

https://{route-information}

By this way ,anyone can see app  from browser, but I don’t want that to be seen by everyone and limit access to specific user.

I heard that this global IP will be allocated  to {route-information}  by default.
Is there any way to limit access to only between specific users? (For example,is there any function like “private registry” at  Kubernetes in Cloud Foundry which  is not open to public)

Since I am using Cloud Foundry in IBM Cloud it would be better if there is solution using IBM Cloud.
I’ve already  granted cloud foundry role to the other user.

Thank you.

Comment: You deployed an Internet app based on Cloud Foundry and want to limit access to it, correct?

Comment: Hello. Yes, that is correct.Than you.

Comment: You could only allow access to authenticated users. There are many ways to implement it, one is with using the App ID service. There are tutorials for it.

Answer (score 2):

The CloudFoundry platform itself does not provide any access controls for applications. If you assign a public route to your application, where the DNS is publicly resolvable and the foundation is on the public Internet, like IBM Bluemix, then anyone can access your app.

There's a number of things you can do to limit access, but they do require some work on your part.

1. Use a private DNS. You can add any domain you want to Cloud Foundry, even ones that don't resolve. That means you could add `my-cool-domain.local` which does not resolve anywhere. You could then add a record to `/etc/hosts` for this domain or perhaps run DNS on your local network to resolve this DNS domain and direct traffic to the CloudFoundry.

   With this setup, most people cannot access your application because the DNS domain for the route to your application does not resolve anywhere. It's important to understand that this isn't really security, but obscurity. It would stop most traffic from making it to your app, but if someone knew the domain, they could add their own `/etc/hosts` header or send fake `Host` headers to access your application.

   This type of setup can work well if you have light security requirements like you just want to hide something while you work on it, or it can work well paired with other options below.
2. You can set up access controls in your application. Many application servers & frameworks can do things like restrict access by IP address or require user access (Basic auth is easy and it is OK, **if you're only allowing HTTPS traffic to your app** which you should always do anyway).

   You can use OAuth2 to secure apps too. Again, many app servers & frameworks have support for this and make it relatively simple to secure your apps. If you don't have a corporate OAuth2 solution, there are [public providers you can use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OAuth_providers). Exactly how you do OAuth2 in your app is beyond the scope of this question, but there's plenty of material out there on how to do this. Google information for your application language/framework of choice.
3. You could set up an access Gateway. This would be an application that's job is to proxy traffic to other applications on the foundation. The Gateway could be something like Nginx, Apache HTTPD, or Spring Cloud Gateway. The idea is that the gateway would be publicly accessible, and would almost certainly apply access controls/restrictions (see #2, many of these proxies have access control options that only take a few lines of config). Your actual applications would not be deployed publicly though. When you deploy your actual applications, they would only be on the internal Cloud Foundry domain.

   CloudFoundry has [local domains](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes), often `apps.internal` (run `cf domains` to see if that shows up), which you can use to easily route traffic across the internal container-to-container network. Using this domain and the C2C network, you can have apps deployed to CF that are not accessible to the public Internet, except through your Gateway.

   Again, how you configure this exactly is outside the scope of this question, but check out the docs I linked to for info on using the C2C network & internal routes. Then check out your proxy server of choice's documentation.